# Hiding content controls in Word Office JS

Tags: ms-word, office-js

Is there a way to hide a content control *and* its content based on some conditions using Office.js?

I know the technical way is to use `<w: vanish/>` in the XML or set the Hidden font effect in the font properties, but I don't see an equivalent `Range` or `Font` property.

I need to hide the content control, not delete it or its contents as I need to maintain its editability.

Answer (score -1):

You can hide the content control acetate by using the appearance property, but this will not hide the content for that you will have a couple of options.

1. replace the OOXML of the content control range
   cc.getRange().insertOOXML with "replace" and use the markup you
   mention.
2. you could also store the content in an XML part and
       insert the content control when you need it in the place you need
       it.    not sure if this will be useful for your scenario

.

if you can try to use the content control appearance=hidden, and then it will be non visible but still there. here is a quick sample on how to do this.

```js
async function run() {
    await Word.run(async (context) => {
        context.document.contentControls.getFirst().appearance = "hidden";
        await context.sync();
    });
}
```

Comment: That only hides the content controls look and feel. Not the content

Comment: oh, sorry I missed that part of the question. the only way to do this is by replacing the OOXML of the content control and add the tags you need, then.